EXCEL - INDEX MATCH WITH MULTIPLE CRITERIA
Asking for help here. I'm trying to get an specific price per tier. For Example, if I'm looking for A1B2C3 with a quantity of 13, the price should show as 6, I used Index Match but when the quantity exceed the max of final tier which is 20, it's giving me #N/A instead of 4. Can anyone help me on how can I solve this?
This is my current formula : =INDEX(I4:I11,MATCH(1,(F4:F11=M4)*(M5>=G4:G11)*(M5<=H4:H111),0))
I can't upload the picture due to lack of points.
I tried adding additional condition like if statement but it's not giving me the correct value or giving me an error like #N/A.



F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N




Product
Start Tier
End Tier
Price







A1B2C3
1
5
10


Product
A1B2C3



A1B2C3
6
10
8


Quantity
21



A1B2C3
11
15
6


Price
#N/A
This should return 4


A1B2C3
16
20
4









You can solve it by changing your final tier, that is, 20, to a very large number, such as 100000000.

Thank you for your insight, Rachel. Though the products that I have more than 8k so it will be hard if I'm going to update all final Tier quantities to large numbers. Hence, I'm asking if there will be a way to do that with Index Match.

"when the quantity exceed the max of final tier which is 20, it's giving me #N/A instead of 4" and "it's not giving me the correct value or giving me an error like #N/A." — if the final tier tops-out at 20, then an error like #N/A is the correct value.  If you don't want that, you can use use IFERROR to do something to the error (which will cause issues if you can have the opposite error — something lower than the smallest tier), or you can use something like =EXP(99) to set the top of your final tier to an absurdly large number

@Chronocidal is there a way for me to utilize the =exp in the formula? I have different quantities on the final tier so I'm not sure how can I do this. I really appreciate all help :)

I think I managed to do a workaround using a helper column and If condition. Thank you so much @Chronocidal.

Why not use the LOOKUP() function here. ? --> =LOOKUP(2,1/((M2=F2:F5)*(M3>=G2:G5)),I2:I5)

... or remove the condition *(M5<=H4:H111) from your formula.

Remove the last condition as @VBasic2008 suggests, but use XMATCH so can search from last to first:  =INDEX(I4:I11,XMATCH(1,(F4:F11=M4)*(M5>=G4:G11),0,-1))

=XLOOKUP(M3,(M2=F2:F5)*G2:G5,I2:I5,,-1) "-1: - Exact match. If none found, return the next smaller item"

Do an INDEX/MATCH on the filtered data:
=LET(_z,F:I,_f,FILTER(_z,TAKE(_z,,1)=M2),INDEX(TAKE(_f,,-1),MATCH(M3,CHOOSECOLS(_f,2))))



You can simplify =LET(_z,F:I,_f,FILTER(_z,TAKE(_z,,1)=M2),INDEX(_f,MATCH(M3,CHOOSECOLS(_f,2)),4))

With XLOOKUP, looking at the Start Tier only

with [match mode] -1

Exact match. If none found, return the next smaller item


when multiplying, M2=F2:F5 is 1 when equal

=XLOOKUP(M3,(M2=F2:F5) * G2:G5, I2:I5,, -1)


